# How to know if a score already exists in a sorted set in redis without knowing the member itself?

Tags: redis

I have a sorted set that contains unique JSON strings. Each string has a unique score (sorted sets does not force unique scores though). Is there any way to know if a certain string in the set has the score ,say 100056, without knowing the string itself?

Comment: Have your tried using the [`ZRANGEBYSCORE` command](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below, say the score you want to search is 100

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE key 100 100
```

If the return is an array with length > 0 => a key with that score is already exists

Answer (score 0):

> ZADD racer_scores 10 "Norem"
> (integer) 1
> ZADD racer_scores 12 "Castilla"
> (integer) 1
> ZADD racer_scores 8 "Sam-Bodden" 10 "Royce" 6 "Ford" 14 "Prickett"
> (integer) 4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).